# Can I deploy a docker container to Azure Webapp

Tags: azure, docker

I found a lot of resources online on using docker with Azure virtual machines. But didn't find any on using docker with Azure Webapps. Is this possible?

Comment: It's not the question of "Can you" instead "Should you". I myself struggling between ACS and Azure Web Apps for hosting my LOB .Net web apps (around 100 in number). With the both the options seem viable, I am having difficulty choosing one over other.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No. Web Apps are a [Platform-as-a-Service](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/services/app-service/) from Azure which use a bespoke packaging and runtime, you can't just create a Web App, point it to a Docker image and run it as a container.

If you want to run Docker on Azure, you can spin up a VM to use as a single host - you can use an Ubuntu image for Linux containers or a Windows Server 2016 image for Windows containers (*currently in preview*).

To create a Docker Swarm running on Azure you can use [Azure Container Service](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/services/container-service/) or [Docker for Azure](https://beta.docker.com/docs/azure/).

Comment: This answer is now outdated as Azure does now support [Docker containers on web apps](https://buildazure.com/2016/11/18/deploy-docker-containers-to-azure-web-apps-on-linux/).

Answer (score 26):

Things are changing fast in the cloud. Since November 2016, it is now possible on linux web apps to run docker containers. You can read about it here. https://buildazure.com/2016/11/18/deploy-docker-containers-to-azure-web-apps-on-linux

Comment: Anyone knows  azure stack support Web App On Linux?

Comment: Not to my knowledge. It is also still in preview in public azure, and there is probably a lot of generally available services they want to make available in azure stack, before they start working on preview services.

Comment: Tutorial Link https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/containers/tutorial-custom-docker-image

Answer (score 0):

No, because a webapp is a PaaS that Azure provides, that allows you to push a website with there settings (to simplify it) with ease.

But, you can push a website onto docker using Azure.

Answer (score -3):

Web Apps, running under App Service, is Webapp-as-a-Service. Nothing to do with Docker. It has its specific methods of code deployment built-in, and does not support Docker images.

That's not to say you cannot have Web Apps and Docker images communicate between each other - you can certainly have, say, your database in a Docker container, being called by your Web App.